# SON Manipulator in mongo queries

Tags: pymongo

I've written a SON manipulator to encode some custom objects into mongo following http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/examples/custom_type.html.  This works brilliantly for encoding and decoding the objects on their way into and out of the collection, but as far as I can tell, there's no way to use it in a query.  If I try to query using an object which can be encoded using the manipulator, I get the same `cannot encode object` error that you get if you try to insert the object directly without using the manipulator.  However, I can obviously query perfectly if I manually encode the object into the query.  Is there a neat way to use the SON manipulator in queries without resorting to manually encoding the object?

Comment: As far as I know you have to overwrite the query methods to achieve this behaviour.  Natively, the query methods expect encodable objects, and as you've discovered, the SON manipulator only manipulates the objects themselves on the way in or out of the db.  However, you could overwrite the query methods of the Collection class so that your custom objects are translated.